# cin: No Operator Found Which Takes A Left-Hand Operand

Tags: c++, syntax, cin

I'm trying to get two space-separated variables and running into this error, as well as [no operator ">>" matches these operands] and [syntax error: ">>"].

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

...

void player(char array[][ROWS_AND_COLUMNS], char letter)
{
    bool element_occupied = false;

    do
    {
        int row = 0;
        int column = 0;
        cout << "Enter player " << letter << ", row and column:";
        cin >> inputValidate(row, 1, 3) >> inputValidate(column, 1, 3);

        if (array[(row - 1)][(column - 1)] == '*')
        {
            array[(row - 1)][(column - 1)] = letter;
            element_occupied = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Sorry, that spot is taken." << endl;
            element_occupied = false;
        }

    } while (element_occupied == false);
}
```

`inputValidate()` takes the input, minimum value, and maximum value, and returns the input value if it is 1, 2, or 3.

EDIT:

```
int inputValidate(int user_number, int lowest, int highest)
{

    while (!(cin >> user_number) || (user_number < lowest || user_number > highest))
    {
        cout << "Error. Enter a number from " << lowest << " to " << highest << ": ";
        cin.clear();
    }

    return user_number;
}
```

This is a tic-tac-toe game.

Comment: In your own words, where you have written `cin >> inputValidate(row, 1, 3) >> inputValidate(column, 1, 3);`, what do you expect that to mean? In particular: *what variables should be read into* (changed as a result of reading data from the standard input)?

Comment: Please show the actual and complete error messages. What does `inputValidate()` actually look like? And more importantly, what does it return exactly? Is `inputValidate()` a plain function, or a stream manipulator? I have a feeling I know the answer, but I will need to see more of your code to be sure. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: The cin is supposed to receive two space-separated integers and read them into row and column.
inputValidate is an int function; I've attached it above.

Comment: The  code is  "C2678 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputValidate()` returns a *temporary* `int`, an rvalue, which `operator>>` can't read into. It expects an lvalue instead (ie, a variable with a name). That is why you are getting errors on the `cin >> inputValidate(...)` statement.

Even if the statement could compile, it simply doesn't make sense to use. `inputValidate()` does its own reading of `cin`, so `player()` shouldn't be trying to pass the return value of `inputValidate()` to `cin >>` to begin with. `inputValidate()` would read in a validated number and return it, then `player` would be trying to read in a new unvalidated number to overwrite it.

For that matter, there is no point in passing in the `user_number` parameter at all. You are passing it in *by value*, just to immediately overwrite it with user input. So the value passed in by `player()` is irrelevant. If you want to `return` the user's input then `user_number` should be a local variable inside of `inputValidate()`. Otherwise, it should be an output parameter passed *by reference* instead, and `inputValidate()`'s return value should be `void`.

Also, when `operator>>` fails inside of `inputValidate()` due to invalid input, you are not discarding the input that caused it to fail. `cin.clear()` only resets the stream's error state, it does not discard any data. You need to call `cin.ignore()` for that.

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

...

int inputValidate(int lowest, int highest)
{
    int user_number;

    do
    {
        if (!(cin >> user_number))
        {
            cout << "Invalid. Enter a valid number: ";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
        else if (user_number < lowest || user_number > highest)
        {
            cout << "Error. Enter a number from " << lowest << " to " << highest << ": ";
        }
        else break;
    }
    while (true);

    return user_number;
}

void player(char array[][ROWS_AND_COLUMNS], char letter)
{
    int row, column;

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter player " << letter << ", row and column:";
        row = inputValidate(1, 3) - 1;
        column = inputValidate(1, 3) - 1;

        if (array[row][column] == '*')
            break;

        cout << "Sorry, that spot is taken." << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    array[row][column] = letter;
}
```